# line break in tabular

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I try to set a line break within a tabular environment where the column is not definded with p{$width}. I've tried the following without the expected result

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
expected result:

\begin{tabular}{|p{15mm}|l|l|}
\hline
X1\newline{}X2 & text & another text\\\hline
\end{tabular}

real result:

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
X1\newline{}X2 (no newline) & a text & another ext\\\hline
\begin{tabular}{l}
X1\\
X2
\end{tabular}
 & a text (not on top) & another text\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Are there any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put into another tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\Stack#1{\tabular[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\endtabular}
\begin{document}
expected result:

\begin{tabular}{|p{15mm}|l|l|}\hline
X1\newline{}X2 & text & another text\\\hline
\end{tabular}

real result:

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
\Stack{X1\\X2} & a text & another ext\\\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
X1\\
X2
\end{tabular}
 & a text (not on top) & another text\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Is there a possibility to set in one cell a tabular environment on top (like \Stack) and in another a center vertical alignment?

Comment: `\newcommand\Stack[2][t]{\tabular[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\endtabular}` then `\Stack{...}` and `\Stack[c]{...}` is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I misread your tables so the first answer was nonsense.

`l` columns are like `\mbox` they do not allow linebreaking. You need to use a `p` column or nest another structure such as a tabular or parbox in teh cell to allow more than one line, just as you would for `\mbox` or `\fbox`

Comment: it does not change the result (using pdflatex TeX-Live 2012)

Comment: now I've got the solution: the inner tabular environment has to be set to top: \begin{tabular}[t]{l}